Перезапись значений в value checkbox'a через input
Eсть фрагмент кода, есть n'e количество строк из таблицы которые подтягиваются из БД, каждая строки имеет уникальную информацию и name в checkbox'e (Нужно для дальнейшей обработки). Сейчас получается так, изменение intup первой строки переписывает value всех checkbox.  Нужно при внесении значения в input,это значение переносилось в value checkbox'a в строке которого вносилось изменение.
Нужно отслеживать input в строке из цикла, и если он изменен вносить изменение этого input в value checkbox'a?
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="table-hover">
                            <?php foreach ($stock as $key => $part) : ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><?= $key + 1 ?></th>
                                    <td><?= $part['name'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $part['quantity'] ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                            <input name="stock<?= $part['id'] ?>" class="check form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2<?= $part['id'] ?>" value="option2">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2<?= $part['id'] ?>">
                                                <input id="valCheck" type="number">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

<script>

   $('#valCheck').on('input keyup', function(e) {
        var value = this.value;
        $(".check").attr("value", value);
    });
</script>


Попробуйте так:
$('#valCheck').on('input keyup', function(e) {
        var value = this.value;
        $(this).closest('.form-check').find('.check').val(value);
    });

С помощью $(this).closest('.form-check') можно подняться наверх по DOM-у от инпута и затем уже провалиться вниз до чекбокса через .find('.check')
Просто сейчас у Вас понятно, что $('.check') будет перезаписывать все чекбоксы, найденные на странице, а $(this) обычно помогает внутри обработчиков событий получать ссылку на себя и уже от него дальше ходить по дереву

Отрабатывает, но теперь меняется только первая строка, в остальных строках скрипт не работает. По логике он же должен отслеживать именно тот imput  в котором я меняю значение, и от него подниматься наверх.

Нужно уйти от ID input, т.к он одинаковым создается для каждой строки в цикле, нужно чтобы скрипт обращался именно к конкретному input  без привязи по id или name или class. Как обратиться к input из множества в которой вносятся данные ?

Работает! Спасибо за наводку !
$('input[type="number"]').on('input keyup', function(e) {
    var value = this.value;
    $(this).closest('.form-check').find('.check').val(value);

});

